# Sending managedObject through to tableview within XIB

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Stuck!

Hey guys, I'm working on trying to move an managed object over to a tableview within an Xib that I've created when the user presses the plus button. I would like to fill the button using core data, called "DeckID". As I haven't been coding for long, I'm not at all familiar with Core Data. It could perhaps be done using prepareforsegue but I'm not sure. I've been racking my brains on it for some time! The code is included for your reference.

Any help at all would be much appreciated!

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"viewCard"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *deckID = [object valueForKey:@"deckID"];

        //Set the variable before it is declared!
        AddCardVC *addC = segue.destinationViewController;
         = [object valueForKey:@"deckID"];


    }

    //The else is to ask the obvious statement; if it is not above, then be low.
    else{

        viewAll *viewing = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewing = segue.destinationViewController;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `NSManagedObjectContext *managedContext;` property in your view controller then you can send a managed object reference to the new view controller when the **"+"** button is pressed.

```
- (IBAction)addCardButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    // Get our managed object reference.
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *cardEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Card" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedContext];

    [request setEntity:cardEntity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *cards = [self.managedContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    // Prepare to manually transition when the back button is pressed.
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];

    // The @"AddCard" identifier is the Storyboard identifier found in Xcode's storyboard properties
    AddCardVC * addC = (AddCardVC *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddCard"];
            addC.cards = cards;

   [self presentViewController:addCardVC animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

A couple of things to note.

- I assume you have a entity in Core Data called `Card`.
- I assume you are not using a `UINavigationController`. If you wish to maintain a bread-crumb (it is typically recommended) for the user to *go back*, you would want to use a `UINavigationController`
- I assume you have set the View Controller's *Storyboard ID* to "AddCard" in Xcode's identity inspector.
- I assume you have set up a IBAction between your UIButton "Add Card" and your View Controller.
- The call to `[self.managedContext executeFetchRequest];` returns an array. I make the assumption that your AddCardVC view controller contains a public property in its header that is a NSArray called `cards`.

Your AddCardVC.h should have the cards array or a single card object property so you can set it like I did above.

```
@interface AddCardVC : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *cards;
@end
```

I am a little confused, because your topic title says sending through a tableview, yet you ask how to do it when the user press a + button. In the event that you need to send the managed object associated with your tableview when the user presses on a cell, you can do that as well by implementing a delegate method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];

    AddCardVC *addCardVC = (AddCardVC *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddCard"];
    addCardVC.cards = [self.managedObjectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self presentViewController:addCardVC animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Again, this does not provide any breadcrumbs for the user to return to. If you want the user to return to the previous screen you would have to add a back button and code it yourself just like we did above.

If you want an example using a UINavigationController let me know and I can put one together.

Comment: A brilliant and extremely helpful answer! Much appreciated! Apologies for the confusion, I mean that I'm trying to send data through to a tableview within a view, activated upon clicking an add button on the viewAllCards screen, as I'm relatively unfamiliar with XIB views, it is a tad confusing.

Comment: Glad that it helped! Please mark it as answered if this addresses your problem :)